# snail motion and snail tracks

Tags: zoology

I took a picture of a snail whose tracks are not continuous. What is the reason? Does the snail lift itself from the ground during its motion?

[image: snail tracks]

Comment: something to do with a rythmic organ contraction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

During particularly dry weather some snails will only touch the ground with part of their "foot" at once. In effect moving more like a desert snake in the image below. They do this to reduce moisture loss. Even though it is still a continuous motion it leaves a discontinuous trail. the same number of these points of contact are present the entire time at no point does it leave contact, think of it more like high stepping. This behavior is sometimes called "jumping" even though it has nothing to do with actual jumping.

[image]

http://www.molluscs.at/gastropoda/index.html?/gastropoda/morphology/locomotion.html

Comment: thanks, do you know of any videos showing these different types of motion?

Comment: sorry no I don't